# Adding rails web-site to a server running php web-site (linux)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, apache

I have two sites hosted on one server, `site1.com` and `site2.com`, both of them are written on php

`site1.com` points to default location which is `/var/www/html/`

`site2.com` is configured in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/site2.com.conf` file. Contents of the file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site2.com
    ServerAlias www.site2.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@site2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site2/
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I wrote another web-application, site3. site3 is written on ruby on rails framework. At the moment I start it with `rails server -b 0.0.0.0` command at `/var/www/html/site3/` directory and access it by entering 'site1.com:3000' url in browser.

What I want to do: create a configuration, which will map 'http://site3.com' url to `/var/www/html/site3/` directory.

Comment: I believe you should point apache to the public folder of your rails app 

**DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site3/public**

Comment: [Check this out](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Thank you! Which parameters should I use in order to run rails server on 80th (http) port without conflict with existing configuration? Or am I getting the whole thing wrong?

Comment: Oh, I see, there is no need to run rails server, apache can handle this with Passenger module